# property originTypeObj does not exist on type "{}"

Tags: javascript, typescript, form-data

After uploading files I get typescript error **property originTypeObj does not exist on type "{}"**

```
    formData.append("front_img", new Blob([front_img.originTypeObj as any]));
    formData.append("back_img", new Blob([back_img.originFileObj as any]));
```

I know I should create type for originTypeObj, but can not figure it out how, since I am really new in typescript.

Comment: Could you add more context? (1) What are those `front_img` and `back_img` objects? (2) Does this error occur during TS compilation or at runtime?

Comment: @PiotrSzyma, `front_img` and `back_img` are files which I have uploaded. `originTypeObj` is the real object file. I have to send it too backend. The error occur during TS compilation.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it to give my front_image and back_image state type:

```
const [front_img, setFrontImg] = useState<UploadFile<any> | null>(null);
const [back_img, setBackImg] = useState<UploadFile<any> | null>(null);
```

and then append them to formData like this:

```
formData.append("front_img", new Blob([front_img?.originFileObj as any]));
formData.append("back_img", new Blob([back_img?.originFileObj as any]));
```